# Баг в форматировании на выборах модераторов

Tags: дефект, дизайн, выборы

Баг в форматировании на выборах модераторов:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`position: fixed` ?

Comment: 1. Да, fixed. 2. Там даже замену top:0 на bottom:0 сделали при достижении низа экрана, так что думаю, это намеренно.